Azure Document Intelligence - prebuild-layout - find original page number in markdown result
I'm using the Azure Document Intelligence service to analyze different types of documents.
I set the output format style in Markdown to be able to have more information regarding the structure and formatting of the document.

To get the result in markdown in Python code I use the following code:

document_intelligence_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(
            endpoint=os.getenv("DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_ENDPOINT"),
            credential=AzureKeyCredential(os.getenv("DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_KEY"))
        )

        poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document(
            "prebuilt-layout",
            AnalyzeDocumentRequest(bytes_source=self.__file_bytes.read()),
            output_content_format=ContentFormat.MARKDOWN,
        )
        result: AnalyzeResult = poller.result()

This code works, no error. It returns correct Markdown formatted text.
If the original document contains a footer with the page number, a specific tag with the detected page number is reported in the Markdown result.
Document footer:

Markdown result tag:

However, if the original document does not have a footer with the page number, in the Markdown result I find no indication of the division of the pages, but it turns out to be a single entire document.
Analyzing the JSON structure returned by the Document Intelligence service I saw that a subdivision of the document into pages and lines is returned for each page.
(screenshot in python code)

I tried to rebuild the pages using the "content" property of lines elements, but the textual result is not the same as the entire text in Markdown.
Furthermore, it happens that if a page ends with a table or an image before the page footer with the page number, the page number does not turn out to be the last actual line of the page, this makes it difficult to structure an algorithm to identify the end of pages in the result in Markdown.


Is there anyone who has encountered the same problems as me? Can anyone recommend an effective method for splitting the result in Markdown format while maintaining the page subdivision of the original document?

please share the code and error in text formate also

Code added in original question!

The sample code below finds the original page numbers in the Markdown result generated by the Azure Document Intelligence service.
It prints the content that you've marked with Markdown context from the Excel file with page numbers:
with  open(path_to_xlsx_file, "rb") as  f:

poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document(

"prebuilt-layout", analyze_request=f, content_type="application/octet-stream"

)

result: AnalyzeResult = poller.result()

  

# Process the analysis result

for  page  in  result.pages:

print(f"----Analyzing layout from page #{page.page_number}----")

for  word  in  page.words:

# Check if the word is marked with Markdown context

if  word.content.startswith("```") and  word.content.endswith("```"):

print(f"Markdown Content: {word.content}, Confidence: {word.confidence}, Offset: {word.span['offset']}, Length: {word.span['length']}")


We get Endpoint, Key of Document Intelligence in the Azure portal.
I used this sample Excel data.
The below code is to get data with page numbers:
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.documentintelligence import DocumentIntelligenceClient
from azure.ai.documentintelligence.models import AnalyzeResult

endpoint = "DOCUMENTINTELLIGENCE_ENDPOINT"
key = "DOCUMENTINTELLIGENCE_API_KEY"

document_intelligence_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))

# Path to your XLSX file
path_to_xlsx_file = "C://Users//Inventory.xlsx"

# Open the XLSX file as a binary read mode
with open(path_to_xlsx_file, "rb") as f:
    poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document(
        "prebuilt-layout", analyze_request=f, content_type="application/octet-stream"
    )
    result: AnalyzeResult = poller.result()

    # Process the analysis result
    for page in result.pages:
        print(f"----Analyzing layout from page #{page.page_number}----")
        for word in page.words:
            print(f"Content: {word.content}, Confidence: {word.confidence}, Offset: {word.span['offset']}, Length: {word.span['length']}")


Search for in the Excel file with page numbers:

# Words to search for in the Excel file

marked_words = ["Laptop", "Monitor", "Keyboard", "Headphones", "Smartphone", "Tablet", "Router", "External Hard Drive", "Wireless Earbuds", "Webcam"]

  

# Open the XLSX file as a binary read mode

with  open(path_to_xlsx_file, "rb") as  f:

poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document(

"prebuilt-layout", analyze_request=f, content_type="application/octet-stream"

)

result: AnalyzeResult = poller.result()

  

# Process the analysis result

for  page  in  result.pages:

print(f"----Analyzing layout from page #{page.page_number}----")

for  word  in  page.words:

if  word.content  in  marked_words:

print(f"Content: {word.content}, Confidence: {word.confidence}, Offset: {word.span['offset']}, Length: {word.span['length']}")





Updated code :

document_intelligence_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))

# Path to your XLSX file
path_to_xlsx_file = "C://Users//Inventory.xlsx"

# Words to identify Markdown content
markdown_identifiers = ["```"]

# Open the XLSX file in binary read mode
with open(path_to_xlsx_file, "rb") as f:
    poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document(
        "prebuilt-layout", analyze_request=f, content_type="application/octet-stream"
    )
    result: AnalyzeResult = poller.result()

    # Process the analysis result for each page
    for page in result.pages:
        print(f"----Analyzing layout from page #{page.page_number}----")
        page_content = []

        # Collect words from the current page
        for word in page.words:
            page_content.append(word.content)

        # Join words to form the complete text of the page
        full_page_text = " ".join(page_content)

        # Split the text into Markdown blocks
        markdown_blocks = full_page_text.split("```")

        # Process each Markdown block
        for i, block in enumerate(markdown_blocks):
            if i % 2 != 0:
                print(f"Markdown Content (Page {page.page_number}):\n{block}\n")

                # Here, you can add additional processing for paragraphs, tables, images, etc.
                # For example:
                # - Identify paragraphs: split by double newlines
                # - Identify tables: look for table syntax in Markdown
                # - Identify images: look for image syntax in Markdown

                paragraphs = block.split('\n\n')
                for paragraph in paragraphs:
                    if paragraph.startswith('|') and paragraph.endswith('|'):
                        print(f"Table (Page {page.page_number}):\n{paragraph}\n")
                    elif paragraph.startswith('![') and '](' in paragraph:
                        print(f"Image (Page {page.page_number}):\n{paragraph}\n")
                    else:
                        print(f"Paragraph (Page {page.page_number}):\n{paragraph}\n")




Thanks for the detailed answer! If I interpreted your code correctly, your solution allows you to get all the words belonging to a page. This is very useful, but in my case I need to have the markdown code for each page, because I then need it to perform operations on paragraphs, tables and images.
I've tried trying to identify pages in the full text in markdown by dividing them based on the position in the text of the starting and ending word, but I don't get a reliable result.

Updated a sample code

For now the problem is still present as having only the words contained in the file divided by page is not enought in my case. I would need all the markdown code for the page itself. Thanks!

You can split the markdown content using the properties from result.pages.
di_result_md_pages = {}

for page in result.pages:
    start = page.spans[0]['offset']
    end = page.spans[0]['offset'] + page.spans[0]['length']
    
    content = result.content[start:end]
    di_result_md_pages[page.page_number] = content

This will result in a dictionary with the original page number as key and the markdown content as value.
Originally found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78750151
